# Decode a string in hexadecimal representation

Tags: r, string

In R, what is an efficient way to convert a string encoded in hexadecimal, such as `"40414243"` to its equivalent characters e.g. `"@ABC"`?

For instance, the equivalent of this code:

```
library(stringr)

FromHexString <- function (hex.string) {
  result <- ""
  length <- str_length(hex.string)
  for (i in seq(1, length, by=2)) {
    hex.value <- str_sub(hex.string, i, i + 1)
    char.code <- strtoi(hex.value, 16)
    char <- rawToChar(as.raw(char.code))
    result <- paste(result, char, sep="")
    char
  }
  result
}
```

Which produces:

```
> FromHexString("40414243")
[1] "@ABC"
```

While the above code works, it's not efficient at all, using a lot of string concatenations.

So the question is **how to write an idiomatic, efficient R function that does this operation**.

Edit: My sample works only for ASCII encoding, not for UTF-8 encoded byte arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test if that is more efficient (for longer strings):

```
string <- "40414243"

intToUtf8(
  strtoi(
    do.call(
      paste0, 
      as.data.frame(
        matrix(
          strsplit(string, split = "")[[1]], 
          ncol=2, 
          byrow=TRUE), 
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)), 
    base=16L)
)
#[1] "@ABC"
```

Otherwise you could look for a C/C++ implementation.

Comment: (+1) though I think you should convert it to a function, otherwise it is hard to use it properly

Comment: Dang- you beat me by 90 seconds *and* wrote a cleaner implementation!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sure, that's true for a lot of answers here. It's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can I please? I won't be able to sleep at night otherwise

Comment: I tried, though got some wierd results for strings such `string1 <- "404142446465642442443"`

Comment: @DavidArenburg My code assumes two digit hex values. You need an even number of characters in the string.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't benchmark it, but the style is what I was looking for: idiomatic, using functions instead of loop and string concatenation. I also edited my question to make it clear that my original algorithm (and your reimplementation) only work for ASCII-encoded strings (since each byte is processed as an individual character), not for a string representing an UTF-8 encoded byte array. I'll leave that for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code so that it uses [lookup tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) an example for [R here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-work-with-lookup-tables-in-r.html). Your lookup table will have 255 values. Put them in vector and get their values from that vector.

Not: No other solution will beat this one if you need to do a lot of conversions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a lookup table (or just like codegolfing :-) ) , consider writing a vectorized version of something like:

```
bar <- unlist(strsplit(foo,'')) #separates input into individual elements
items <- sapply(1:(length(bar)/2),function(j)paste0(bar[(2*j-1):(2*j)],sep='',collapse=''))
```

followed with `strtoi` or whatever.

But even easier (I hope...)  is

```
sapply(1:(nchar(foo)/2) function(j) substr(foo,(2*j-1),(2*j)))
```

Comment: Using `sapply` != vectorized.

Comment: @Roland my sloppy grammar -- I meant to write a vectorized version of the task executed with `sapply`

Comment: Thanks. After fiddling with your answer, this works: `intToUtf8(strtoi(sapply(1:(nchar(string)/2),function(j)paste0(unlist(strsplit(string,''))[(2*j-1):(2*j)],sep='',collapse='')), base=16))`.